# How do I configure Firestarter to allow NetBIOS name lookups

Tags: samba, firestarter

When Firestarter is running (using default settings), I can't look up names of local Windows shared PCs (`nmblookup` fails with `ERRNO=Operation not permitted`). This also means I can't browse the shares with Nautilus.

When I click the "stop" button, `nmblookup` succeeds and I can browse the shares with Nautilus.

How do I configure Firestarter's policy to solve this?

(Firestarter is v1.0.3 under Ubuntu 11.10.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Firestarter, install GUFW. The default configuration of GUFW doesn't interfere with NetBIOS lookups.

Firestarter does not seem capable of allowing this, at least via its GUI.

Answer (score 0):

### Server

Samba uses the following ports:

```
netbios-ns = 137/tcp # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-dgm = 138/tcp # NETBIOS Datagram Service
netbios-ssn = 139/tcp # NETBIOS session service
microsoft-ds = 445/tcp # if you are using Active Directory
```

Port 445 (TCP) - NetBIOS was moved to 445 after 2000 and beyond, (CIFS).

You need to allow those ports in Firestarter.

### client

The samba client uses ports 1327/udp and 138/udp.

Comment: Hmm. That didn't work, but maybe Firestarter can't handle UDP filtering.